# Rigged low poly charector deforms when moving

Tags: rigging, armature

Whenever i try to move my Armature on my moddel it just deforms (See Gyazo underneath)

https://gyazo.com/7e69fd15d5ac351e89e700787c42935a

This is my first blender creation so there is a good chance i made a mistake while making the character

[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: There are a lot of duplicated verts in your model. Remove them then parent again with automatic weights. In the mesh's edit mode select everything and hit alt+m and select by distance.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed adding two of the upper arm vertices to the arm vertex group so they stay in their original position while the rest of the arm moves. In Edit mode, select the arm.l vertex group by hilighting it in the R/H pane and clicking 'Select'. Then Shift-click on each of the vertices I've indicated on the model and click the 'Assign' button in the R/H pane it should work ok. You seem to have done the same with most of the head vertices. That shows an even worse problem!

[image]

Comment: Thx! this seems to work!

Comment: You're welcome. As Ffeller says you also have lots of overlapping vertices in the mesh too which is probably why the problem happened in the first place. In Edit mode press 'A' to select the whole mesh then 'M' and Merge By Distance to merge the duplicates. You'll see a brief message in the bottom status bar that 36 overlapping vertices have been removed!